# Revalidate in Next.js 13.4 doesn't seem to work

Tags: mongoose, next.js, next.js13

The following code does not work as desired. The page is not rendered again after the 5 seconds have elapsed. If I open the page, then another tab and come back, I see in the debugger that the page is executing other requests, but not this one. No matter how long I also stay on the page, apart from the initial request, no new request is made. I use Next.js with the Route Handler (13.4)

app/page.js

```
import MainImage from "./MainImages/page";
import { mongoConection } from "../lib/mongoConnection";
import Product from "./model/Product/page";

export const revalidate = 5;

const fetchFromMongoDb = async () => {
 try {
   mongoConection();
 } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

 const allProducts = await Product.find({}).sort({ createdAt: -1 }).limit(20);

 return allProducts;
};

export default async function Home() {
const products = await fetchFromMongoDb();

return (
 <div className="pb-10 dark:bg-gray-900 dark:text-white">
   <MainImage products={products}></MainImage>
 </div>
 ) ;
}
```

app/MainImages/page.js:

```
export default function MainImage({ products }) {
const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
 console.log("New Products...");
 console.log(products[0]);
 setResult(products);
}, [products]);
```